# Como mejor la salida de datos de un csv

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo csv que tiene Nombres y otras propiedades y tengo un método que dependiendo de una condición me filtra los nombres en esta caso : Guárdame los nombres de las personas que no fueron denunciados como desaparecidos

```
@Override
    public String ListaPersonas(){
        List<String> ListaDeNombres = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Csv_ orden:lista){
                if (orden.Reportado() == false){ListaDeNombres.add(orden.Nombre());}
            }
            return ListaDeNombres.stream()
                    .map(e->e.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Csv_ : es donde esta el csv guardado en una lista
y .Me sale correctamente lo que quiero

```
Griff Titcombe
Vaclav Ovell
Ingram Rostern
Abigale Alsop
Edeline Millsom
Halimeda Brooker
Lynna Stolle
Pieter Finney
Harman Fantonetti
Natasha Shakelady
Winnah Costa
Dara Harmes
Corabella Pheasey
Ulla Danovich
Alric Quibell
Cris Bottrell
Chet Reddell
Sharia Baldry
...........
```

sin embargo no quiero que aparezca como lo de antes si no que fuera así:

```
Griff Titcombe   Griswold Carolan
Vaclav Ovell     Nico Lassetter
Ingram Rostern   Karalee Bewley
Abigale Alsop    Cinnamon Juris
Edeline Millsom  Edeline Millsom
Halimeda Brooker ...............
Lynna Stolle
Pieter Finney
Harman Fantonetti
Natasha Shakelady
Winnah Costa
```

quiero limitar las apariciones como en 5 nombres y después en otra columna 5 , no se como limitarlo y ponerlo así.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Aquí estamos para ayudarte, no para hacerte el trabajo

Comment: @Enrique si te fijas arriba tiene código esto : ``@Override
    public String ListaPersonas()`` etc.

Comment: @Enrique el trabajo ya esta hecho , solo pido un consejo como mostrarlo para que se va mas presentable , si lo dejo como lista esta bien sin embargo yo no quiero dejarlo así es mas por gusto. lo que me piden ya esta hecho .

Comment: Para realizar ello en más de 1 columna, lo único que se me ocurre es crear una lista que recorra la anterior y en cada múltiplo de 5, se añadan los nombres al string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que el String obtenido a partir del método `ListaPersonas()` esta delimitado por un salto de linea("\n");

```
String nombres="Griff Titcombe\nVaclav Ovell\nIngram Rostern.....
```

esto puedes ser convertido en un `array` usando `split()` y posteriormente en un `array bidimensional` para agrupar cierta cantidad de nombres en columnas

```
String[]datos=nombres.split("\n");
```

haciendo uso de [Instream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-)  convertimos el array en un arrayBidimensional limitando la cantidad de columnas,obtenido el arrayBidimensional se imprime haciendo uso de `String.format()`

```
static void imprimir(String []arr,int columnas){

String[][] matriz = IntStream
        .iterate(0, i -> i < arr.length, i -> i + columnas)
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays
                .stream(arr, i, Math.min(i + columnas, arr.length))
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

 
 for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++ ) {
    for (int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++) {
         System.out.print(String.format("%20s",matriz[i][j])+"\t");
    }System.out.println("");
  } 

    }
```

[**Ejecución**](https://paiza.io/projects/e/4eQdGTMWql7cX3S3Rx9ztg?theme=twilight)

**Salida**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]